# How do i revert an image back after using np.copy?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

```
def boxing(original_img,predictions)
  newImage = np.copy(original_img)
  for result in predictions:
    .
    .
    .
    return newImage

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.imshow(boxing(imgcv, result))
```

Hey! I passed a np.copy(image) into the boxing function and returned a newImage. Above is the gist of my code and the ... part is just drawing bounding boxes and overwritting the NewImage. How do i convert the resultant [newImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8sLn.jpg) back to it's original form after the function?

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
new_im = Image.fromarray(boxing(imgcv, result))
ax.imshow(new_im)
```

From what i understand, i am supposed to use Image.fromarray to convert it back but I had no success. I understand this may be a silly question but I appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: do you want to revert all the operations done on `newImage` inside the function, if yes,then why would you want to do this, doesn't the  doing `np.copy()` is the whole point not to change the `original_image`

Comment: I want to revert the original image back to it's original color. The operations were done on the np.copy() to draw the bounding boxes for detection. For image detection, it would be a problem if it changes the output image.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The issue is that the image is in BGR.

```
new_im = cv2.cvtColor(boxing(imgcv, result), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

This essentially converts the image back to RGB. Hope it helps!